# i keep getting this error execution failed for task 'appprocessdebugmanifest'

Tags: android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:67:13-72
is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:63:9-67:75 to override.
```

//heres the code

```
<activity>
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: You should post the code that you think is responsible for causing this error.

Comment: you have an answer in you error.

Comment: i tried that it doesnt help. when i did that i got 17 errors

Answer (score 0):

i solved it the best way i could. by removing facebook all together.